# Hyper-V Manager MMC SnapIn in Windows 2008 Web Edition. Possible?

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v, mmc

Is there any possibility to run Hyper-V Manager MMC SnapIn on Windows 2008 Web edition ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is against the Web Editions EULA.

Answer (score 1):

Too bad. But this is quite strange if you think about it. MS has released Hyper-V Manager MMC SnapIn for Vista so why they could'n release it for Windows 2008 Web Edition? This is only a manager ..